# ASP.NET MVC5 website and TypeScript app together on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, typescript, publishing

I have two projects. The 1st one is `ASP.NET MVC5` website which is some king of administration panel.

In the same solution exists `HTML TypeScript` application that works using `AJAX`. It's something client-like for displaying some data based on configuration made in the admin module and database data.

I would like to publish them both as a one website in `Windows Azure` cloud. I don't know how to do this when I have two projects. I was also unlucky finding some information in `Google` :(

I hope I don't need to move my `TypeScript` project files into `ASP.NET MVC5` :/

Answer (score 0):

> hope I don't need to move my TypeScript project files into ASP.NET MVC5 :/

You should do that. How else would your web app serve the generated JS if it's not a part of the webapplication.